# Find parameters of the posterior Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, bayesian

The question is to find $p(x|y)$ given that
$p(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and $p(y|x) \sim \mathcal{N}(Ax, \Gamma)$.

I do realize that I may just obtain a posterior through application of the Bayes Theorem, but the integration would be onerous.
$$p(x|y) = \frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{\int{p(y|x)p(x)dx}}$$

I have been made to know a certain trick, where $y$ posed as $y = Ax+ \epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Gamma)$. Then the $p(y)$ parameters  are derived rather easily: $p(y) \sim \mathcal{N}(A\mu, A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma)$. Hence, we have evidence and are relieved from the integration in denominator.

Yet I cannot come up with the next step of solution. Tips and suggestions are the most welcome.
Thanks.

**Edit**
Let's write down the distributions we have (neglecting the constant term): 
$$p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Sigma|}}exp(-\frac 1 2(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu))$$
$$p(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Gamma|}}exp(-\frac 1 2(y-Ax)^T \Gamma^{-1}(y-Ax))$$
$$p(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma|}}exp(-\frac 1 2(y-A\mu)^T {[A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma]}^{-1}(y-A\mu))$$

Then, $p(x|y) = f(x,y)exp(g(x,y))$ and f(x,y) might be expressed as:
$$f(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{|A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma|}{{|\Gamma||\Sigma|}}} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\Gamma \Sigma [A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma]^{-1}|}}$$.
Then, $Cov(x|y) = \Gamma \Sigma [A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma]^{-1}$.

But I get stuck on rewriting $g(x,y)$ term:
$$g(x,y) = -\frac 1 2(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) -\frac 1 2(y-Ax)^T \Gamma^{-1}(y-Ax) + \frac 1 2(y-A\mu)^T {[A \Sigma A^T + \Gamma]}^{-1}(y-A\mu)$$

Comment: Well, if you know all the distributions, it's a matter of dividing and not making errors in the algebra.

Comment: BTW, there are issues with your notation which leave you prone to confusion. Typically we use a capital letter $X$ to denote a random variable, $p_X(x)$ to for it's probability density function, where $x$ is a value that the RV may take, and we say $X \sim p_X(x)$ where $p_X$ may be an a gaussian, as it is in your case. So, I would write $Y = AX + \epsilon$, instead of $p(y) = Ax + \epsilon$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 It is not a plain algebra, at least for me. As I understand it, the conjugate distributions must be used. Yet, you are welcome to prove me wrong. Regarding your second comment, it seems heavenly opinion-based. Yours notation involves a substantial degree of redundancy and, at least to my experience, is not that common. I suggest you against editing my question to comply with it.

Comment: You have $p(y|x) = A\exp (f(x,y))$, $p(x) = B\exp(g(x))$, and $p(y) = C\exp(h(y))$. Surely you can attempt to calculate the rations as required by the formula you have written above. If you find it to be problematic, at least add where you got confused to the question. With regard to notation, beyond the pedantic subscripts, which I too drop when clear from the context, this is pretty standard notation, and has in the past helped me avoid confusion. You're welcome to not use it, but it has its merits, such as disallowing incosistent statements like equating the density of the function with...

Comment: ...the value a different random variable attains.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I indeed had a mistake in $y = Ax + \epsilon$ equation. It is consistent now. I also added progress I made. I would be grateful if you take a look.

Comment: Hint: Keep only the $(\ast)$ part in the exponentials $\exp\left(-\frac12(\ast)\right)$ and get rid of the terms independent of $x$. One gets a quadratic expression in $x$ depending on $y$, namely, $$(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+(y-Ax)^T\Gamma^{-1}(y-Ax),$$ that one wants to transform into $$(x-\nu)^TU^{-1}(x-\nu)+\kappa,$$ for some parameters $(U,\nu,\kappa)$ possibly depending on $y$, the value of $\kappa$ being irrelevant. One gets $$U^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}+A^T\Gamma^{-1}A\quad \nu=U(\Sigma^{-1}\mu+A^T\Gamma^{-1}y),$$ from which one can deduce $(U,\nu)$. One sees that ...

Comment: ... $U$ does not depend on $y$, $\nu$ does, and the conditional distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y=y$ is $\mathcal N(\nu,U)$.

Comment: @Did I am clueless about transformations behind the conversion of $(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)+(y-Ax)^T\Gamma^{-1}(y-Ax)$ to $(x-\nu)^TU^{-1}(x-\nu)+\kappa$. Could you give me a tip?

Comment: This is quadratic in $x$ hence one simply has to identify the order $2$ term $x^TU^{-1}x$ to get $U^{-1}$. Similarly for the order $1$ terms.

Comment: @Did, I got the $U^{-1}$ result. But cannot obtain $\nu$. While opening given exression I am getting following 1 order terms: $-x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu -\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x + y^T\Gamma^{-1}Ax - x^TA^T\Gamma^{-1}y$. The part $(\Sigma^{-1}\mu+A^T\Gamma^{-1}y)$ is visible from here, but why $\nu$ is prefixed by $U$?

Comment: Good news: "the value of $\kappa$ is irrelevant" (quote).

Comment: @Did. I meant $\nu$, sorry. And $\nu$ is relevant. I'm already did the edit to previous comment.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense--but I already explained that one goes for the order $1$ terms, equalling $$\nu^TU^{-1}x+x^TU^{-1}\nu=\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}x+x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu+(Ax)^T\Gamma^{-1}y+y^T\Gamma^{-1}(Ax).$$